# SQLite 3.8.8 in Ubuntu 14.04 via apt-get

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, sqlite3

How to install the SQLite 3.8.8 in Ubuntu 14.04 via apt-get?

The default installation is for 3.8.2.

Thanks, Christian

Answer (score 1):

base on the SQLite project page on launchpad: https://launchpad.net/sqlite/+packages

The latest version 3.8.8 is not available yet for Ubuntu. You can't install it with apt-get command now.

You could download the "Precompiled Binaries for Linux" form SQLite's website: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: Thank you P.-H. Lin You're right the version 3.8.8 is not available yet for Ubuntu 14.04. Anyway, is there a way to install the 3.8.6-1 (14.10) in Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)?